# change mouse pointer in swf file

Tags: flash, adobe

I have a game file in a .SWF. The cursor in the SWF is  very small, and I would like to change the cursor in SWF file.

Is it possible to change the cursor for built SWF file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a chance to change the mouse pointer in the game other besides changing the size of the mouse pointer for your whole system. ;)
For anything else, you'd need the source file(s) and recompile the game.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [CursorManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/CursorManager.html) class and its [setCursor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/CursorManager.html#setCursor%28%29) method.

[This post](http://www.flex-blog.com/set-custom-cursor-using-the-cursormanager/) tells the story pretty well

**EDIT**

Since you only have the swf, you can add a wrapper, and change the cursor in that.

Or you could decompile it and then do the needful